# Installing xorg-x11-devel package in SLES 11 SP2

Tags: linux, imagemagick, x11, xorg, zypper

I am using `Imagemagick(6.4.3.6-7.18.x86_64)` in `SLES11 SP2`

Using it like bellow..

> import -window $wid $jpg

and getting this ***error***

> import: DelegateLibrarySupportNotBuiltIn `' (X11) @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/1303.

This [LINK](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=14055) ***suggests to install the X11 `development package.***

I search for the **package**(`zypper se xorg-x11-devel`) and it's available but when i try to install that getting this message..

> zypper in xorg-x11-devel
>
> Loading repository data...
>
> Reading installed packages...
>
> Resolving package dependencies...
>
> Problem: nothing provides libuuid1 = 1.41.1 needed by libuuid-devel-1.41.1-13.9.x86_64
>
> Solution 1: do not install xorg-x11-devel-7.4-8.18.x86_64
>
> Solution 2: break libuuid-devel by ignoring some of its dependencies
>
> Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c] (c): c

Checked for the `libuuid1` package and this one is already installed on my system.

> zypper info libuuid1
>
> Loading repository data...
>
> Reading installed packages...
>
> Information for package libuuid1:
>
> Repository: SUSE-Linux-Enterprise-Server-11-SP2 11.2.2-1.234
>
> Name: libuuid1
>
> Version: 2.19.1-6.29.3

Now what should be my next step, remove the current `version(2.19.1-6.29.3)` of `libuuid1`  and back to the mentioned older version `libuuid1 = 1.41.1`?

If i do so what problems i might face?

or any other idea/suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: libuuid is used by many things like udev, devmpper, etc so rolling it back probably not a best idea. Try finding newer devel packages for libuuid and X11 like from SLED sp2 or dev kit.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Installed the updated version of `libuuid-devel` and also able to install `xorg-x11-devel`
@lonewasp can you please put your comment as an answer to this question. I will be able to accept it then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libuuid is used by many things like udev, devmpper, etc so rolling it back probably not a best idea. Try finding newer devel packages for libuuid and X11 like from SLED SP22 or dev kit.